# Typescript recursive generic type with conditions?

Tags: typescript

For a generic function,

```js
function func<T>(arg:T):T {
  return arg
}
```

the `T` is inferred from the argument

Consider this use case:

```js
type RecursiveType<OK extends boolean = false> = { // 1
  isOK: OK;
  property: OK extends true ? ("a"|"b") : 0;
  children?: Array<RecursiveType>; // 2
}

const recursive:RecursiveType = {
  isOK: true;
  property: 'a',
  children: [
    {
      isOK: false,
      property: 0
    },
    {
      isOK: true,
      property: 'b'
    },
  ]
}
```

TS complains `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'`.

But if I remove the default type, now I have to give an argument to `children`'s type, otherwise `Generic type 'RecursiveType' requires 1 type argument(s).`

How to declare the `RecursiveType` properly so that when create the variable, my editor could give correct type hints for `property`?

Is there any way to make ts infer `OK`'s type, just like the generic function do?

Comment: This kind of inference is not possible without a function to do the inferring for you.

Comment: I don't see why you are using generic and conditional types at all here; why not just make this a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) as shown [in this TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKR7gm)?  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer, but if you really do need some kind of recursive generic conditional then I'd like to see a better [mre] that isn't as easily replaced by a discriminated union.  Please let me know either way (and remember to @jcalz mention me or I won't see your reply)

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case you have to declare type. Because inferred is not suitable.

```
type RecursiveType<OK extends boolean = false> = { // 1
  isOK: OK;
  property: OK extends true ? ("a"|"b") : 0;
  children?: Array<RecursiveType>; // 2
}

const recursive:RecursiveType<true> = {
  isOK: true,
  property: 'a',
  children: [
    {
      isOK: false,
      property: 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. The `children` is an Array and some children may have `isOK: true`, then the same error: `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'`